# Как экранировать get запрос php

Tags: php, get

Отправляю get запрос через file_get_contents:

```
file_get_contents($config['api_server'].'?action=add&domainid='.$config['domain_id'].'&name='.$name.'&meta='.$meta.'&html='.$html.'&active='.$active.'&session='.$config['session']);
```

Проблема такая что в &html у меня находится целая страница с пробелами и разными символами которые могут нарушить целостность запроса. как можно этого избежать?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php  только передавать html в GET не лучшая идея, там все таки серьезные ограничения на длину URL. В IE вроде 2048 символов

Comment: @Mike , если get отправляется из Php а не из браузера, будут ли ограничения?

Comment: У web-серверов свои ограничения. У Апача по умолчанию 8Кб, хотя можно в конфиге менять. по другим серверам смотреть надо.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) для параметров по-отдельности.

Или, что будет лучше, запишите все GET-параметры в массив и воспользуйтесь функцией [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php), чтобы она уже сама корректно отформатировала параметры.

```
$queryargs = [
    'action' => 'add',
    'domain' => $config['domain_id'],
    // и т.д.
];
file_get_contents($config['api_server'].'?'.http_build_query($queryargs));
```

В комментарии к вопросу верно сказано, что через GET-параметры существенный объём данных лучше не передавать. Насколько существенный - вопрос сложный, стандарт HTTP этого не описывает, так что лимиты бывают очень разные. Больше килобайта-двух лучше не рассчитывать.

Если дизайн API ваш - то технически и семантически будет лучше данные передавать в теле запроса методом POST или PUT (для действия добавления сущности семантически более корректно PUT, POST для редактирования имеющейся).

Comment: Плюс, но, пожалуйста, добавьте информацию об ограничении по длине запроса